# QList<T*> to qml array

Tags: c++, qt, qml

I have a class Bar which inherits from QObject. I want to have a QList of Bar pointers in class Foo and expose it in qml.

foo.h

```
#ifndef FOO_H
#define FOO_H

#include <QQuickItem>

class Bar : public QObject
{
    Q_OBJECT
    Q_PROPERTY(int x READ x)

public:
    explicit Bar(QObject *parent = nullptr)
        : QObject(parent), mX(123) {}
    virtual ~Bar() {}

    int x() const { return mX; }
private:
    int mX;
};

class Foo : public QQuickItem
{
    Q_OBJECT
    Q_PROPERTY(QList<QObject *> t1 READ t1)
    Q_PROPERTY(QList<Bar *> t2 READ t2)

public:
    explicit Foo(QQuickItem *parent = nullptr)
        : QQuickItem(parent) {
        mT1.append(new Bar(this));
        mT1.append(new Bar(this));

        mT2.append(new Bar(this));
        mT2.append(new Bar(this));
    }
    virtual ~Foo() {}

    QList<QObject *> t1() const { return mT1; }
    QList<Bar *> t2() const { return mT2; }

private:
    QList<QObject *> mT1;
    QList<Bar *> mT2;
};

#endif // FOO_H
```

qmlRegisterType("Custom.Foo", 1, 0, "Foo");

main.qml

```
import QtQuick 2.6
import QtQuick.Window 2.2
import Custom.Foo 1.0

Window {
    visible: true
    width: 640
    height: 480
    title: qsTr("Hello World")

    MouseArea {
        anchors.fill: parent
        onClicked: {
            console.log(foo.t1)
            console.log(foo.t1.x)
            console.log(foo.t2)
            console.log(foo.t2.x)
        }
    }
    Foo {
        id: foo
    }
}
```

`QList<QObject *>` works I can access it's member `x` and `console.log(foo.t1)` outputs `qml: [Bar(0x10e4be0),Bar(0x10bd6d0)]` but `QList<Bar *>` doesn't.
When I try to access member `x` I get qml: undefined and `console.log(foo.t2)` outputs `qml: QVariant(QList<Bar*>)`.

Why `QList<Bar *>` is exposed in QVariant? Is there a way to expose it in qml same way `QList<QObject *>`?

Comment: What is exactly task you solve? It seems your example code is oversimplified. It is rare case, when just immutable (from both QML and C++ sides) list needed. I suspect you need a model for a listview or something alike.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

First off read the following article carefully:

- [Data Type Conversion Between QML and C++](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qtqml-cppintegration-data.html)

In order to create JavaScript arrays or objects from C++ data structures, you should expose those of C++ in `QVariantList` (which gets converted to JavaScript array) or `QVariantMap` (which gets converted to JavaScript object).

Also section *"Sequence Type to JavaScript Array"* says:

> Certain C++ sequence types are supported transparently in QML as JavaScript Array types.
>
> In particular, QML currently supports:
>
> ```
> QList<int>
> QList<qreal>
> QList<bool>
> QList<QString> and QStringList
> QList<QUrl>
> QVector<int>
> QVector<qreal>
> QVector<bool>
> ```

In your case, note that:

> Other sequence types are not supported transparently, and instead an instance of any other sequence type will be passed between QML and C++ as an opaque `QVariantList`.

Therefore, you should prepare your list in a `QVariantList`. Also note that since both `QVariantMap` and `QVariantList` are of type `QVariant`, so you can insert a map into a list or vice versa, to create a complex array of objects or a complex object having a list inside.

Comment: `QObjectList` (`QList<QObject*>`) and `QAbstractItemModel` can also be used : http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qtquick-modelviewsdata-cppmodels.html

Comment: @GrecKo for the QObjectList aternative you suggest, would QList<Bar*> not be allowed? Bar is of type QObject and QObjectList is QList<QObject*>. Would there be a problem with the type converstion between type Bar* and QOjbect*?

Comment: @piper2200s `QList<Bar*>` is not allowed even if Bar inherits from QObject. As an alternative you could use http://gitlab.unique-conception.org/qt-qml-tricks/qt-qml-models/

Answer (score 6):

QML Engine recognizes `QList<QObject*>` as a special case. You can't expose a property of type `QList<Bar*>`, the engine doesn't understand it, and there is no way to register it as a new list type.

Another option which hadn't been mentioned is **casting the list**... *as sinful as it may be considered by some.*

If you must have your data stored in `QList<Bar*>` then you can return it as a `QList<QObject*>` as below...

```
QList<QObject *> t2() const {
    Q_ASSERT(sizeof(QObject*) == sizeof(Bar*));               // check pointers are the same size
    Q_ASSERT(sizeof(QList<QObject*>) == sizeof(QList<Bar*>)); // check lists are the same size
    Q_ASSERT(qobject_cast<Bar*>((QObject*)mT2.at(0)));        // check Bar is derived from QObject
    return *reinterpret_cast<const QList<QObject *>*>(&mT2);  // now cast the list
}
```

It's fast, easy, and all the object properties and Q_INVOKABLE methods of the Bar class are available in QML.

I've added a few checks in just in case, but if you can be certain your class is derived from QObject then you might choose not to bother.

`QList<QObject*>` support is documented here: http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qtquick-modelviewsdata-cppmodels.html#qobjectlist-based-model. It is no coincidence that it is a special case... it has been chosen to be a special ;) Each `QObject*` is copied from the `QList` and used to create a new javascript array inside the QML Engine.

Encompassing things inside a `variant` is fine, so long as the engine knows the type which is inside the `variant`. You can register `Bar` type so that the QML engine could understand:

- `QVariant(Bar*)` and even
- `QList<QVariant(Bar*)>`.

However you can never get the engine to understand `QList<Bar*>`.

(note: if `Bar` derives from `QObject`, then there is no need to register it to QML, support will be implicit)

Other options...
`QQmlListProperty` and `QList<QVariant>` will work, but have been covered in other answers.
`QAbstractListModel` is another option, but there are already enough resources elsewhere to see how that is done.

full code:

### foo.h

```
#ifndef FOO_H
#define FOO_H

#include <QQuickItem>

class Bar : public QObject
{
    Q_OBJECT
    Q_PROPERTY(int x READ x)

public:
    explicit Bar(QObject *parent = nullptr)
        : QObject(parent), mX(123) {}
    virtual ~Bar() {}

    int x() const { return mX; }
private:
    int mX;
};

class Foo : public QQuickItem
{
    Q_OBJECT
    Q_PROPERTY(QList<QObject *> t2 READ t2)

public:
    explicit Foo(QQuickItem *parent = nullptr)
        : QQuickItem(parent) {
        mT2.append(new Bar(this));
        mT2.append(new Bar(this));
    }
    virtual ~Foo() {}

    QList<QObject *> t2() const {
        Q_ASSERT(sizeof(QObject*) == sizeof(Bar*));               // check pointers are the same size
        Q_ASSERT(sizeof(QList<QObject*>) == sizeof(QList<Bar*>)); // check lists are the same size
        Q_ASSERT(qobject_cast<Bar*>((QObject*)mT2.at(0)));        // check Bar is derived from QObject
        return *reinterpret_cast<const QList<QObject *>*>(&mT2);  // now cast the list
    }

private:
    QList<Bar *> mT2;
};

#endif // FOO_H
```

### main.cpp

```
#include <QGuiApplication>
#include <QQmlApplicationEngine>

#include "foo.h"

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    QCoreApplication::setAttribute(Qt::AA_EnableHighDpiScaling);
    QGuiApplication app(argc, argv);

    QQmlApplicationEngine engine;

    qmlRegisterType<Foo>("Custom.Foo", 1, 0, "Foo");

    engine.load(QUrl(QLatin1String("qrc:/main.qml")));
    if (engine.rootObjects().isEmpty())
        return -1;

    return app.exec();
}
```

### main.qml

```
import QtQuick 2.6
import QtQuick.Window 2.2
import Custom.Foo 1.0

Window {
    visible: true
    width: 640
    height: 480
    title: qsTr("Hello World")

    MouseArea {
        anchors.fill: parent
        onClicked: {
            console.log(foo.t2)
            console.log(foo.t2[0].x)
            console.log(foo.t2[1].x)
        }
    }
    Foo {
        id: foo
    }
}
```

Comment: So if I understood correctly what engine doesn't understand/support encompasses in `QVariant`? What's intresting that engine supports `QList<QObject*>` but it seems it's not documented anywhere. And I suppose `QVector<QObject*>` or `QMap<QString, QObject*>` is also not supported by the engine. Then why `QList<QObject *>` is so special?

Comment: Added some more info to the answer to address your comments. `QList<QObject*>` support is documented here: http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qtquick-modelviewsdata-cppmodels.html#qobjectlist-based-model. Sorry I don't know much about QML support for `QVector` and `QMap`. My guess would be that there is zero support for either.

Comment: Encompassing things inside a variant is fine, so long as the engine knows the type which is inside the variant. In fact what you are seeing with `QVariant(QList<Bar*>)` is the QML engine wrapping your `QList<Bar*>` inside a `QVariant` itself (as it does for most object types), but is then unable to unpack the variant because it does not understand the type `QList<Bar*>`.

Answer (score 4):

To expose a list of `QObject` to Qml, Qt recommends to use `QQmlListProperty`.

To create this object you need to override some of its access function, like `size()`, `at()`, etc.

You should have a look to

- http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qqmllistproperty.html
- http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qtqml-referenceexamples-properties-example.html

Answer (score 1):

Here is how I would do it using `QQmlListProperty`. It takes awhile to get used to it, but it works exactly the way you'd expect.

Foo.h

```
#ifndef FOO_H
#define FOO_H

#include <QQuickItem>

class Bar : public QObject
{
    Q_OBJECT
    Q_PROPERTY(int x READ x)

public:
    explicit Bar(QObject *parent = nullptr)
        : QObject(parent), mX(123) {}
    virtual ~Bar() {}

    int x() const { return mX; }
private:
    int mX;
};

class Foo : public QQuickItem
{
    Q_OBJECT
    Q_PROPERTY(QQmlListProperty<Bar> bars READ bars)

public:
    explicit Foo(QQuickItem *parent = nullptr)
        : QQuickItem(parent) {
        mBars.append(new Bar(this));
        mBars.append(new Bar(this));
    }
    virtual ~Foo() {}

    QQmlListProperty<Bars> bars();
    void appendBar(Bar*);
    int barCount() const;
    Bar *bar(int) const;
    void clearBars();
    void replaceBar(int, Bar*);
    void removeLastBar();

private:
    QList<Bar *> mBars;
};

#endif // FOO_H
```

Foo.cpp

```
#include "Foo.h"

QQmlListProperty<Bar> Foo::bars()
{
    return {this, this,
            [](QQmlListProperty<Bar> *prop, Bar *newBar)
            {
                Foo *foo = qobject_cast<Foo*>(prop->object);
                if (foo) {
                    foo->appendBar(newBar);
                }
            },
            [](QQmlListProperty<Bar> *prop)->int
            {
                Foo *foo = qobject_cast<Foo*>(prop->object);
                if (foo ) {
                    return foo->barCount();
                }
                return 0;
            },
            [](QQmlListProperty<Bar> *prop, int index)->Bar*
            {
                Foo *foo = qobject_cast<Foo*>(prop->object);
                if (foo) {
                    return foo->bar(index);
                }
                return nullptr;
            },
            [](QQmlListProperty<Bar> *prop)
            {
                Foo *foo = qobject_cast<Foo*>(prop->object);
                if (foo) {
                    foo->clearBars();
                }
            },
            [](QQmlListProperty<Bar> *prop, int index, Bar* newBar)
            {
                Foo *foo = qobject_cast<Foo*>(prop->object);
                if (foo) {
                    foo->replaceBar(index, newBar);
                }
            },
            [](QQmlListProperty<Bar> *prop)
            {
                Foo *foo = qobject_cast<Foo*>(prop->object);
                if (foo) {
                    foo->removeLastBar();
                }
            }
    };
}

void Foo::appendBar(Bar* newBar) {
    mBars.append(newBar);
}

int Foo::barCount() const
{
    return mBars.count();
}

Bar *Foo::bar(int index) const
{
    return mBars.at(index);
}

void Foo::clearBars() {
    mBars.clear();
}

void Foo::replaceBar(int index, Bar *newBar)
{
    mBars[index] = newBar;
}

void Foo::removeLastBar()
{
    mBars.removeLast();
}
```